# Unable to Scrape Product Name from otto.de

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

As I apply all possibilities to my code that print all the names of products but in the end printing only one name

I want that it print names till (N) pages

here is my code

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
l=list()
obj={}
listing=[]
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"}
url ="https://www.otto.de/herren/mode/jacken/"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
#content= soup.find_all('div',class_='col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3') 
jackets = soup.find_all("section",{"id":"reptile-tilelist"})
#print(jackets)
for product in jackets:
   title= product.find("a",{"class": "find_tile__content"}).text
   print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use their Ajax API:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.otto.de/everglades/tilelist"
params = {
    "rule": "(und.(ist.sortiment.bekleidung).(ist.zielgruppe.herren).(sind.kategorien.jacken).(~.(v.1)))",
    "l": "gp",
    "o": "0",
}

o, i = 0, 1
for page in range(0, 3):
    params['o'] = page * 116
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.select('.find_tile a')

    for n, title in enumerate(products, i):
        print(f"{n:<3} {title['title']}")

    o += 116
    i += len(products)
```

Prints:

```
1   adidas Sportswear Outdoorjacke ESSENTIALS DAUNENJACKE
2   adidas Sportswear Outdoorjacke UTILITAS 3-STREIFEN HOODED – GENDERNEUTRAL
3   Indicode Kapuzensweatjacke Brekstad
4   Jack & Jones Steppjacke TIMO PUFFER JACKET

...
```

Comment: from where I find Ajax API

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Open Web Developer Tools in Chrome/Firefox, then Network Tab. Reload the page and you should see the url there.